# Derivative on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

- Definition. Let $A \subset \mathbf{R}^{m} ;$ let $f : A \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{n} .$ Suppose $A$ contains a
  neighborhood of a. Given $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbf{R}^{m}$ with $\mathbf{u} \neq 0$ , define

$$f^{\prime}(\mathbf{a} ; \mathbf{u})=\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{a}+t \mathbf{u})-f(\mathbf{a})}{t}$$

provided the limit exists. This limit depends both on a and on u; it is called the **directional derivative** of $f$ at a with respect to the vector $\mathbf{u}$.

- Definition. Let $A \subset \mathbf{R}^{m},$ let $f : A \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{n}$ Suppose $A$ contains $a$ neighborhood of $a$. We say that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if there is an $n$ by $m$ matrix $B$ such that

$$\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})-B \cdot \mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|} \rightarrow \mathbf{0} \quad \text{as} \quad \mathbf{h} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$$ The matrix $B,$ which is unique, is called the **derivative** of $f$ at a; it is denoted
$D f(\mathbf{a}) .$

EXAMPLE. Define $f : \mathbf{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ by setting $f(\mathbf{0})=0$ and
$$
f(x, y)=x^{2} y /\left(x^{4}+y^{2}\right) \text { if }(x, y) \neq \mathbf{0}
$$

We show all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $0,$ but that $f$ is not differen-
tiable at $0 .$ Let $\mathbf{u} \neq \mathbf{0}$ . Then

$$\begin{aligned} \frac{f(0+t u)-f(0)}{t} &=\frac{(t h)^{2}(t k)}{(t h)^{4}+(t k)^{2}} \frac{1}{t} \text { if } u=\left[\begin{array}{l}{h} \\ {k}\end{array}\right] \\ &=\frac{h^{2} k}{t^{2} h^{4}+k^{2}} \\ \text { so that } & \text { if } k \neq 0 \\ f^{\prime}(0 ; \mathbf{u}) &=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{h^{2} / k} & {\text { if } k \neq 0} \\ {0} & {\text { if } k=0}\end{array}\right.\end{aligned}$$

Thus $f^{\prime}(\mathbf{0} ; \mathbf{u})$ exists for all $\mathbf{u} \neq \mathbf{0}.$

**My Question:** How can I show the function $f$ is not differentiable at $0$? How can I show $f^{\prime}(0 ; \mathbf{u})$ is not a linear function of $\mathbf{u}$? Can you help? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from your computations that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$. Therefore, *if* $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, then $f'(0,0)$ would be the null function. In other words, we would have$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert}=0.$$This is the same thing as asserting that$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{(x^4+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$$But this is not true; see what happens if $y=x^2$.